# How to choose between Azure App Service Plans on a slow performing App?

Tags: azure, performance, asp.net-core

Fellow coders,

I know this question is not exactly about programming, feel free to close this issue and point me to the correct Forum if SO is not the appropriate place for it.

I have developped a .NET Core 3.1 App, deployed on Azure App Service, but I face a performance issue.

The service consists of an OCR Analysis of various files, the OCR part being performed by an external library embedded into a DLL. On my laptop, when running the service locally, **the OCR Part** (one line of code, no I/O, nothing else being performed) **takes between one and two seconds**. It takes a big chunk of the available CPU though.

For the exact same file being processed, and monitoring the exact same line of code, **the computation takes 6 to 8 seconds when running online on Azure**, with no other request being processed. The App is deployed on Azure Web App, S1 Production Plan (100 *ACU*, around 60 $/month). With the number of users increasing, the overall response time is increasing as well and this compromises the performance of the entire system.

Before I start switching Plans and spending my customer's money, I would like to make sure that I am not missing something important on how to chose a Web App Plan.

1. First, all other things being equal, should I expect a S1 Production WebApp to be *slower* than my own computer on a CPU Based Job? My laptop is fitted with a multicore i7-7700 CPU. It likely depends on many external parameters but I would like to hear a general rule of thumb if any.
2. When reviewing Max CPU Usage of the Web App, it peaks at 50-60%, cf.screenshot below. Does it mean that CPU usage is not a bottleneck for this process, and therefore that I am missing something else?
3. What readings would you recommend on how to dimension a Web App / Server for a given job?

[image: Max CPU Usage, ApplicationInsight]

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this documentation https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/linux/, the S1 plan has 1 CPU core and 1.75 GB RAM, and I guess this is the reason why on the cloud is taking more time even if the metrics show that the CPU peek only to 50/60%.

For better performance, Microsoft indicates to use PremiumV2 plans ( and now are also available the premium V3), but in your case, I suggest you scale up your plan to S2 and profile the application, then scale up to S3 and so on...

Comment: Microsoft have always pushed hard for people to move to higher tiers, even when it's unnecessary. It's just them upselling.

Comment: It sounds logical that a Premium Plan is better than a Standard one :-) But your approach is exactly what I would like to avoid : increasing plans without understanding of where is the bottleneck. "I guess this is the reason why on the cloud is taking more time even if the metrics show that the CPU peek only to 50/60%", based on what? Can you please point me to resources explaining why your guess is not something out of the air?

Comment: @XavierAM I agree with you , you can profile your application and understand where is the bottleneck , this is the right approach for cost saving and optimization, also based on your requirements.

But seems that your 3 questions are about :
  - the app service plan tier choose and expectations vs your local laptot
  - CPU bottleneck 
  - recommended readings
I tried to cover the point 1 and 3 , for point 2 you can scale up for a moment and see what happen to understand how much benefit you have using another tier ,this should also help to understand if the CPU is the bottleneck or not

Comment: Cpu peek can be only 50% , but your code ( or 3rd part code that you use ) could be designed to take advantage of more  cpu cores and this could be why your application is much more slow than your local laptot .

I am only suggesting to scale up and profile in order to understand better if CPU is the real bottleneck, you scan scale up , profile and then scale down , why not ?

Comment: @pioardi yes that's what I will end up to without any better understanding. Test is already ongoing actually ;-) . I will let you know how it goes when we I get enough data. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: Actually, your "rule of thumb" was better than any complicated approach. I scaled up to PremiumV2 and response time was halved!

Answer (score 1):

Generally you never want a web request to take as long as 6-8 seconds, you need to be thinking about a different architecture ideally rather than beefing up your server.

Your best fit for a relatively quick refactor may well be a combo of azure storage blobs plus a blob storage triggered azure function which does the processing, you should be able to move your code to the azure function. The web site would then just deal with the upload and would return immediately, ideally with some kind of ID that the client could use to check the document status. Other event based mechanisms are also available if you don’t want the client to have to check the status manually.

Comment: Even better, with this approach you'll only pay for what you use with the Azure Function [consumption plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan).

Comment: @Matt, I completely agree with you. I am pushing in this direction as well. But for the time being and for many reasons outside of my reach, the customer wants the processing to be done in a single web request. Doing otherwise would imply to refactor the calling service as well which is not an option yet.